# How can I get a revision id's children?

Tags: python, bazaar

If you run this

```
Branch.open(repository_location).repository.get_revision(revision_id).parent_ids
```

it will return the parent_ids of the specified revision_id.

How can I do this same thing, but instead of returning the parent_ids it returns the children_ids?

I looked through the different properties in the API and didn't find one for children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way in which you can get this information is to scan all the revisions in the repository:

```
child_revids = {}
revs = r.get_revisions(r.all_revision_ids())
for rev in revs:
    for parent_id in rev.parent_ids:
        child_revids.setdefault(parent_id, []).append(rev.revision_id)
```

You probably want to avoid doing this if at all possible, since its performance scales with the size of the repository.

Comment: Yeah I would definitely like to avoid that. I am trying to get back to the most recent whole number revision. So if I have `1000, 999, 990.4.2, 990.4.1, 998, 997`. And if given the revision id of `990.4.1` I would want to output `999`. I was going to use the child_ids to loop through up to the first whole number child. However, this method does not seem plausible.

Comment: There is also not a single revision that is the child - there can be multiple; the revision numbers only have meaning in a specific branch.

Comment: I figured out how I am going to do it, but I will not be using the children. I will use iter_merge_sorted_revisions again to loop through my range in one number increments.